# Wordpress SQL default search, how to handle SQL Injection

Tags: wordpress, sql-injection

Wordpress default `SQL`  search, how to handle `SQL Injection` during the default search.

> example : Sitename.com/?q=test OR 1=1 --
>
> i.e.,
>
> q=test%20or%201=1%20--

Shows all the article.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use three hook,

- 'posts_join' hook join your custom table to the post table
- 'posts_where' hook expand the WHERE clause of the query to look in
  your custom table fields.
- 'posts_groupby' hook add a GROUP BY clause to the query

  ```
  add_filter( 'posts_join', 'prefix_search_join' );
  add_filter( 'posts_where', 'prefix_search_where' );
  add_filter ( 'posts_groupby', 'prefix_search_groupby' );

  function prefix_search_join( $join )
  {
    //global $custom_table contain your custom table name
    global $custom_table, $wpdb;

    if( is_search() ) {
      //your joining sql
    }
    return $join;
  }

  function prefix_search_where( $where )
  {
    if( is_search() ) {
     //Where clause 
     }
    return $where;
  }

  function prefix_search_groupby( $groupby )
  {
    global $wpdb;

    if( !is_search() ) {
      return $groupby;
    }

    //we need to group on post ID
    $mygroupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.ID";

    if( preg_match( "/$mygroupby/", $groupby )) {
      //grouping we need is already there
      return $groupby;
    }
    if( !strlen(trim($groupby))) {
      //groupby was empty, use ours
      return $mygroupby;
    }
    //wasn't empty, append ours
    return $groupby . ", " . $mygroupby;
  }
  ```

for more details, check this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries i hope it'll help you

Comment: hi Nahid, Thanks for the inputs, but i am looking for this one example: User entered "select * from wp_posts" in the search box. Then do a search submission. With the query parameter https://wordpress.org/search/select+%2A+from+wp_posts++-- i.e., Search Results: select * from wp_posts -- (0). I want to customize the search results with out query adding in the place holder.

Comment: For select clause you can use add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'prefix_search_select' );  hook.